# Any optimized technique to set array values in bean?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, javabeans

I'm getting an array with fixed size of let's say 20.

I have to set each array element in a bean property, so my bean has 20 properties.

Here's my current approach:

```
Object[] record = { "0", "1", "2", ...."19" };

for (int j = 0; j < record.length; j++) {
    if (j == 0) {
        bean.setNo((String) record[j]);
    }
    if (j == 1) {
        bean.setName((String) record[j]);  
    }
    if (j == 2) {
        bean.setPhone((String) record[j]);  
    }
    // so on and so forth...
}
```

This is how i'm setting every property of bean from array.

Here i have 20 elements in array.

So to set 20th element it is checking 20 conditions.. Performance issue..

Any optimized technique is appreciated...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is it actually a performance issue or do you just not like it? It seems unlikely that you're setting this so often that it actually matters how optimized it is. Don't optimize until you need to.

Comment: Why are you using that loop (and all the condition checks) there?

Comment: You shouldn't use a loop at all.  You should just have 20 statements in a row that directly access to correct element in the array.

Comment: @jahroy what would be the reason for not to use switch case? Any problem with that? please explain...

Comment: The switch statement is the same as the code you've posted (if you changed your _if_ statements to _if else_ statements).  Internally there will be no difference.  Just because you can't see the _if statements_ it doesn't mean the compiler isn't making the same amount of comparisons.  Your code will make 400 comparisons (because you don't use an _if else_ statement).  The answer with the switch statement will make 200 comparisons (an average of 20 per item).  The answer by @SashiKant will make zero comparisons and will perform 20 efficient operations.

Comment: The real question is this: is it possible to modify the type of _BeanList_?  If you have no choice but to have _BeanList_ contain arrays of Objects, then you should stick with the answer you chose.  _BUT_... it would be way better if _BeanList_ could be a List or whatever type your _bean_ object is.  So, if _bean_ is a _FunkyBean_, you should make _BeanList_ a List of _FunkyBean_ objects.

Comment: Oops: I meant to say an average of **10** comparisons per item above when explaining that the switch statement would make 200 comparisons...

Comment: @jahroy Really wonderful work of you.. Thanks for your time with me correcting my doubts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is :

Try this::

```
     Object[] record = BeanList.get(i);
     int j = 0;
     bean.setNo((String) record[j++]);
     bean.setName((String) record[j++]);  
     bean.setPhone((String) record[j++]);
```

..............
................
.............

Comment: This is a far better answer than the one you selected.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of setting bean values. This requires commons-beanutils.jar as dependency.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public class BeanUtilsTest {

    // bean property names
    private static String[] propertyNames = { "name", "address" };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        // actual values u want to set
        String[] values = { "Sree", "India" };
        MyBean bean = new MyBean();
        System.out.println("Bean before Setting: " + bean);

        // code for setting values
        for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
            BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, propertyNames[i], values[i]);
        }
        // end code for setting values
        System.out.println("Bean after Setting: " + bean);
    }

    public static class MyBean {
        private String name;
        private String address;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }
        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyBean [address=" + address + ", name=" + name + "]";
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

U can use Switch instead of these if statements

```
for( int j =0; j < record.length; j++) {
     switch (j){
           case 1 :  bean.setNo((String) record[j]);break;
           case 2 :  bean.setNo((String) record[j]);break;
           ....
           ....
    }
}
```

Comment: I will.. But atleast i must wait 5 to 10 minutes to accept the answer.. so i'm waiting..

Comment: This does not improve performance in any way.  It is basically the same code written differently.  The answer by @SashiKant is far superior.